# How to indentify if a function being decorated is a function or a method?

Tags: python, static

How can I identify if the current function being decorated is a method (belonging to a class) or a function?

```
class ClassA:
  @mydecorator
    def method(self)
    pass

  @staticmethod

@mydecorator
def function()
  pass
```

mydecorator need to know if the decorated function is:

- a method (is_method)
- a static method (is_static)
- a class method (is_classmethod)
- a global function (is_function)

How can we do this?

Thanks!

Comment: When the decorator is applied, the function is still a function; the method is bound only when accessed from the class (dynamically, each time).

Answer (score 0):

```
is_method = lambda f: hasattr(f, 'im_self')

is_static = lambda f: isinstance(f, types.FunctionType)

is_classmethod = lambda f: getattr(f, 'im_self', None) is not None

is_function = lambda f: not hasattr(f, 'im_self')
```

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types

Comment: This doesn't work on instance on the method (f should be equal to ClassA.method but here we have ClassA().method())